# PDO how to force value to be updated as an int

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have the following pdo statement:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("update product_active set stock=stock-:basketid, sold=sold+:basketid where productid_FK=:pid");

foreach($_SESSION['basket'] as $pid=>$val){
    $stmt->bindParam(":basketid", $_SESSION['basket'][$pid], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(":pid", $pid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

This basically updates the stock, this works locally but on my server only the stock column is updating. I have a feeling this is because sold is probably coming out as a string.

Is there away to force both the updates to be int?

Thanks

Comment: what if you bind all to 3 placeholder , and avoid repeting of :basketid ?

Comment: what if you switch the position of stock and sold. Maybe then only the sold column is updating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not try to use the same named parameter twice in a single SQL statement, you must use each parameter once and only once. Apparently this is expected behavior (according to this bug report: http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=33886)  because of portability issues.

Probably binding each parameter works:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("update product_active set stock=stock-:basketid, sold=sold+:basketid where productid_FK=:pid");

foreach ($_SESSION['basket'] as $pid=>$val)
{
    $basketid = $_SESSION['basket'][$pid];
    $stmt->bindParam(":basketid", $basketid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(":basketid", $basketid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(":pid", $pid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

If not, add another named parameter that gets the same value.

Comment: LOL!!! Just changed the order as @hakre suggested and sold updated and not stock. So tried different paramater names just before you posted and it worked! Starnge but the original code worked locally but not on the server. Anyway thanks all!

Comment: Probably you need to enable error throwing first with PDO. Like `$db = new PDO('sqlite:database.sdb'); // Create a new PDO Object
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // Set Errorhandling to Exception`